# Existence of an element in $K^0$ group, Koszul complexes

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, topological-k-theory

I havee such a question on construction of the Koszul complex (further we are concerned about K-theoretical Euler class). I was thinking of introducing the Koszul complex, and the existing of elements in $K^0(X)$ groups. Here is the picture
[image]

Such an example is a part of https://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/kgeom.pdf (page 113). I don't know exactly how we can deduce existing of the element in $K^0(B,B-s^{-1}(0))$. If anyone has studied any similar approach or can explain how (maybe in geometrical way) one can get elements that later are used to build the K-theory Euler class, it would be great to understand what is going on here.

Moreover, any other papers or suggestions about approaches are more than welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the question about how chain complexes give rise to $K$-theory classes, or why the class is supported only on $s^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: I thought about the first one, but not sure if I get the second neither. I would like to see how we build $K$-theory classes in that way, how they look like..

Answer (score 2):

You should read Definition 5.1 in the notes you've linked to: they explain the definition of $K$-theory classes associated to a bounded complexes of finitely-generated projectives.  It's a little different than some more traditional definitions, but Proposition 5.4 shows that the definitions are the same.

To see that the $K$-theory class defined by the Koszul complex is supported away from $s^{-1}(0)$, note that (i) the complex is exact when pulled back to $B - s^{-1}(0)$, and (ii) exact complexes are zero in $K$-theory (see, e.g., Exercise 5.6).

Comment: For few days I was trying to understand what is going on but I still can't. I don'y undestand the definition $5.1$ firstly. Is there any interpretation (maybe geometric) of it? Then, even beliving in $5.4$, I still can't see the existence in the underlined place.. Can you give me any hints or comments how to get my point?

Comment: The way to relate the $K$-theory of a ring to the $K$-theory of a nice space $X$ is to take the ring to be $\mathcal{C}(X)$, the ring of continuous functions on $X$, since f.g. projective modules over $\mathcal{C}(X)$ are the same as vector bundles on $X$ - this is the Serre-Swan theorem, which is also discussed in the notes.  Going the other way is taking the spectrum of the ring. Using complexes instead of modules is kind of a way to preempt the formation of $K$-theory...

Comment: ...a complex is a way to resolve a vector bundle/projective module/coherent sheaf, and you can think of it as a "formal alternating sum" (the Euler characteristic, as Dugger explains in the proof of 5.4).  Finally, by the LES (or by definition), a bundle on $B$ that is zero on $B - s^{-1}(0)$ automatically gives a class in relative $K$-theory.

Comment: I got some intuition how it works, thanks a lot. any hints how to do exercise 5.6 maybe?